# "Type of expression ambiguous without more context" when using Core Data with SwiftUI

Tags: core-data, swiftui

Trying to use EnvironmentObject to populate a view with data from Core Data.

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @EnvironmentObject var quoteStore: QuoteStore

    var body: some View {

        HStack {
            Text(quote.text)
            Spacer()

        }
    }
}
```

And here's the NSManagedObject:

```
extension Quote {
    public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Quote> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Quote>(entityName: "Quote")
    }

    @NSManaged var text: String
    @NSManaged var title: String
    @NSManaged var author: String

    static func create(author: String, text: String, title: String, in context: NSManagedObjectContext) {

        let newQuote = Quote(context: context)
        newQuote.text = text
        newQuote.title = title
        newQuote.author = author
    }
```

I get the error message "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

Comment: Which line is marked with the error?

Comment: Right now, remember that `SwiftUI` in still in early beta - which means very confusing errors (including marking the wrong line of code also). Here's something that *is* wrong from what you've posted - maybe it's the issue, or maybe you just haven't posted enough code. Why did you declare `quoteStore` but are trying to display `quote.text`? My best hint is to go slow... get the view working first. Try to build some logic around it and make sure your `NSFetchRequest` is working - not by displaying it, just working. Then and *only* then try to display it. You might find the actual line.